# Having trouble linking CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Can someone help me figure out why this is not linking correctly?

I have tried to add margins to the `.banner`, but it is not changing anything. I'm also concerned because I do not think atom is recognizing my stylesheet as CSS even though I have labeled it as so.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Interactive Resume Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="Stylesheet-home.css">
  </head>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner {
  margin-left: 26px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the code and not links

Comment: ... and do this as a snippet

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers on this page telling you that the href should contain 'Stylesheets' as the folder that contains your .css file. But that's not something you mentioned in your question, so this advice may not help.

Where are you saving your file? You'll basically want that href attribute to read 'href="FOLDER-NAME/Stylesheet-home.css"' or, if your CSS file is saved in the same directory as your HTML file, it would simply be 'href="Stylesheet-home.css"'.

Answer (score 0):

Change link on  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Stylesheets/Stylesheet-home.css">`

Answer (score 0):

> Ok firstly you should define in the code the exact location of you CSS file. In this case it would be :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/Stylesheet-home.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking for example a index.html and you have your CSS inside of a folder called "css" you must link like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

If this not work maybe is because you have a different tree for your folders and that's why is not calling your CSS properly.